# why is $\bar u \circ \bar v =v \circ u \circ f?$

Tags: commutative-algebra

The proposition 2.9 of Atiyah and Macdonald :

It is written that

> The sequence
> $$M'\xrightarrow u M \xrightarrow v M'' \rightarrow 0$$
> is exact iff  for all  $A$-modules N,  the  sequence
> $$0\rightarrow Hom (M'',N)\xrightarrow{\bar{v}} Hom(M,N)\xrightarrow{\bar{u}} Hom (M',N)$$
> is exact

> Proof :  First  of all  ,since $\bar v$ is injective  for all $N$ it follows that $v$ is  surjective .Next , we have  $\bar u \circ \bar v =0$  that is $v \circ u \circ f =0$  for  all $f : M'' \to N$

**My confusion** :  Im not getting why is  $\bar u \circ \bar v =v \circ u \circ f?$

**My thinking** :$\bar u \circ \bar v=\bar u (\bar v )$

$$\bar v: Hom (M'',N)\rightarrow Hom(M,N)$$

$$\bar u:Hom(M,N)\rightarrow Hom (M',N)$$

$$\bar u \circ \bar v:Hom (M'',N) \to Hom (M',N)$$

$$\implies  \bar u \circ \bar v \in Hom (M',N) \implies \bar u \circ \bar v: M' \to N $$

I think  $\bar u \circ \bar v \neq v \circ u \circ f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, it should be

> Next, we have $\bar u \circ \bar v = 0$, that is $f \circ v \circ u = 0$ for all $f \colon M’’ \to N$.

Why? Well, if $\bar u \circ \bar v \colon \text{Hom}(M’’,N) \to \text{Hom}(M’,N)$ is the zero map, then for every $f \in \text{Hom}(M’’,N)$ we have that
$$
0 = (\bar u \circ \bar v)(f) = \bar u(\bar v(f)) = \bar u(f \circ v) = f \circ v \circ u.
$$